# How to get access only front-facing camera in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

**I want to get access the only front-facing camera when opening Camera View in Flutter.**

My following code works fine for opening the, capture an image, then show the image file in my flutter. ***But I want to restrict the back-camera, only want to get access the Front camera.***

```
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final value;


class SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
File imagefile;
  openCamera(BuildContext context)async{
    var picture = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() {
      imagefile = picture;
    }
    );
  }


 showImage(){
  if(imagefile == null){
    return Text(" My image  here");
  
  }else {
    Image.file(imagefile,width:400,height:400);
  }
}
}

 body: 
        SafeArea(
                  child: Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0,left: 00),
            child:

 Row( children: [ cameraButton(),],
    ),


Widget deviceButton() {
    return RaisedButton( 
      child: new Text('Camera button',)

onPressed: () {

         openCamera(context);
        var value = new MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => new CameraAccess(value:imagefile ),
          );
          Navigator.of(context).push(value);
      }, 
    );
```

Comment: Hi, check this article. They are using camera lib 
    https://pub.dev/packages/camera
    here is the link to article  
     https://inducesmile.com/google-flutter/how-to-use-front-camera-in-flutter/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use preferredCameraDevice: CameraDevice.front

Like:
final picker = ImagePicker();
final imageFile = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera, preferredCameraDevice: CameraDevice.front);